# How to hide the last digit while writing a password in swift

Tags: swift, uikit, passwords, uitextfield

Recently I've been working on a UITextField that hides the password while editing text on the loginPage, password field.

As everyone knows `.isSecureTextEntry = true` solves the problem up to a point. However, while typing the password, the last character appears and is perceived as a security hole in a way. So I could not find out a solution how to solve this. Thank you in advance for your answers.

I attached two pictures.

**The solution offered by UIKIT today.**

[textField.isSecureTextEntry = true](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gvkXh.png)

**It's what I wanted.**

[I want this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3hlaJ.png)

Comment: The last character should "hide" itself after a few seconds, no? It's mainly because keyboard is virtual, so we need to show the user which character was typed.

Comment: Yes, definitely! After a few seconds the last character hides itself. What I want is to hide the last character always. If we want to draw a bad scenario :)  If you assume someone is recording you on camera while you are logging in, they can also learn your password. So I want to implement this on my app, if it is possible. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When ever you input the character the func `textField(_:shouldChangeCharactersIn:replacementString:)` will call to replace old text with new text. So you just need to catch the value and don't let it update by default.

```swift
textField.isSecureTextEntry = true
textField.delegate = self // add delegate to catch the action
```

Get the value when changing in your `TextField` and don't get it update the UI automatically.

```swift
extension ViewController : UITextFieldDelegate {
    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        if let currentText = self.textField.text as? NSString {
            let newText = currentText.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string) // change to new one
            self.textField.text = newText // assign it back to textField text
            return false // don't let it update automically
        }
        
        return true // by default
    }
}
```

If you have multiple `textField` in the screen you must checked if the current changing is your `password` one before. If yes return `false` else return `true` like default.